# School Detention Tracker in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make a spreadsheet for the Deans at my school to track student detentions.  They aren't that great with technology so I want to make it as simple for them to use as possible.

Here is a link to the current layout: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FIW0QAWGStgdUmYU0rWAceWI-YvjM1RIIC_KC2OeWWI/edit#gid=0

It would have a row for every student in the school and use different columns to record when students received a detention and whether or not it has been served yet.  I created a formula to check how many unserved detentions each student has so that the deans can easily sort for who needs to serve detention that day.

I want some help creating two scripts:

1. A button that the deans can click to assign a student a detention.  It would need to find the next available empty cell on that row, input the current date, then find the next available empty cell and write "Issued"
2. A button that the deans can click to mark that student's detentions as served.  It would need to find and replace all instances of the word "Issued" on that row with "Served"

Ideal dean workflow:

1. Issuing a detention - Find the student on the list and click the "Issue" detention button
2. Running detention - Find the student on the list and click the "Served" button
3. Meeting with a parent/looking over records later in the year - Find student on the list and scroll horizontally to view dates of all detentions earned that year.

Potential snags:
One of our deans already sheared a spreadsheet trying to sort it.  Is there a way I can reduce this risk while still giving him the ability to sort by student name and number of unserved detentions as neccesary?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few workarounds in lieu of a macro:

- To input date > ctrl + semicolon, or command + semicolon on macs. This will enter the current date in the cell.
- Use the =countif formula to keep an easily sortable tally on number of detentions a student has been assigned and served
- An if statement can let you know that, if the total count assigned vs. total count served do not match, then a student still has a pending detention.

I also recommend keeping a "viewer" tab that your dean uses and the actual area where people are recording the data separate. That way the dean can sort and manipulate your data without actually affecting the original entries.